# Set of subsequential limits $b_n$ and $a_n$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ denote the set of subsequential limits of $a_n$. Suppose $b_n$ is a sequence in $A \cap R$, where the limit of $b_n$ exists in $R$ unions +- infinity. Show that limit of $b_n \in A$.

I'm having trouble with this as I do not have my facts straight.
I know that the set of values of $b_n$ is a subset of $A$ minus +- infinity and the limit exists.

I also know that it is therefore between the $\liminf a_n$ and $\limsup a_n $ for all $n$, so its limit must be between, but how do I proceed from there?

Is it possible to say that the set of subsequential limits is finite?

If so, how can we pick infinite elements for our sequence from a finite set? Is it allowed to pick the same element more than once?

Comment: Please use MathJax, it makes it much easier to read.